# Is this "Sympathetic fight response" axis accurate?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology

Peripheral sensory cell > Preganglionic cell > Dorsal root ganglia cell in the ''Sympathetic chain'' > Ventral root ganglia cell in the ''sympathetic chain'' > Post-ganglionic cell that activates an organ such as the pancreas (or a muscle).

Answer (score 1):

The typical axis of the **fight response** is depicted in Fig. 1.

[image: ![HPA axis]
<sup>Fig. 1. HPA axis. Source: [Social Psychology principles](http://2012books.lardbucket.org/books/social-psychology-principles/s06-02-emotions-stress-and-well-being.html)</sup>

This axis is the hypthalamus-pituitary-adrenal axis, or [**HPA axis**](http://adrenalfatiguesolution.com/hpa-axis/). It mediates not only the fight response and is typically referred to as the **fight-flight-fright response**. It is the [central stress response system](http://www.integrativepro.com/Resources/Integrative-Blog/2014/The-HPA-Axis) that prepares the body in a fraction of a second for survival, basically under the influence of adrenalin and cortisol produced by the adrenal glands.

The circuit you are describing, by the looks of it, is more typical for a [**reflex arc**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflex_arc) (Fig. 2.).

[image: ![Reflex arc]
<sup>Fig. 2. Reflex arc. Source: [Sweetibnotes](http://sweetibnotes.blogspot.com.au/)</sup>

A typical example of a reflex arcs is the [pain-withdrawal reflex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Withdrawal_reflex). Although the sensory stimulus triggering the reflex arc may also trigger the HPA axis, the basic circuitry of a reflex arc does not include the HPA axis. The pain-withdrawal reflex, for example, is basically designed to jerk a limb away as fast as possible in the presence of acute pain as a protective mechanism.